# Table view with Pagination in Magnolia for content listing

Tags: magnolia

My clients prefer the table view with pagination instead of the default browser view where if there's already a long list, the user have to scroll very long in the browser.

Is there any component in Magnolia that can support this kind of component where there's a pagination instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK is no pagination possible out of the box in the list view of an app.

It is probably not very hard to implement, but you could also get your users used to the search, which will get them much faster to the desired entry than clicking through a lot of paged result lists.